# Using custom URL to make an state change in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i have to redirect to a certain page in ionic app when app is loading from an external URL.

1. i want to redirect to another state from handleOpenURL callback.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: i try to solve with local storage and it did not working..the application is opened and the state change doesnt work

Comment: @MoralesBatovski i solved it..thanks for your comment.

Comment: @sabareesh, since you managed to solve it, try posting the solution and closing the question.

Comment: @RicardoSilva sure. i will post it